# Am I missing a step in trying to use the PlSql Grammar with Antlr4?

Tags: java, plsql, antlr4

If I download the PlSql Grammar files (PlSqlParser.g4 and PlSqlLexer.g4) from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 and run them with Antlr4, this successfully creates the relevant packages. As suggested elsewhere I then paste the two files called PlSqlParserBase.java and PlSqlListenerBase.java and then attempt to compile using the command javac Pl*.java

This gives me the following error which I don't follow.

> PlSqlLexerBase.java:5: error: duplicate class:
>   PlSqlParseTree.PlSqlLexerBase public abstract class PlSqlLexerBase
>   extends Lexer
>                   ^ PlSqlLexer.java:12: error: cannot access PlSqlLexerBase public class PlSqlLexer extends PlSqlLexerBase {
>                                   ^   bad source file: ./PlSqlLexerBase.java
>       file does not contain class PlSqlLexerBase
>       Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath. 2 errors

I assume I must be missing an obvious step. Can someone aid me in getting the sources to compile?

Comment: "As suggested elsewhere I then paste the two files called PlSqlParserBase.java and PlSqlListenerBase.java" Paste them where? Where and in which context was that suggested? Copying files is definitely not part of the standard build process for ANTLR projects.

Comment: In other stackoverflow questions it is stated that plsql grammar needs language specific functions for it to work and therefore that an additional two files are needed for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compile by commenting out package line in PlSqlLexerBase.java and PlSqlParserBase.java.

```
//package PlSqlParseTree;
```